# Datatable export to excel working for ".xls" format but giving error for ".xlsx" format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I have the following code to download a DataTable as an excel file.This code is working if i download as ".xls" format , but its not working if i download as ".xlsx" format.

```
var filename = "Students.xlsx";
var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
grid.DataSource = dt;
grid.DataBind();

//customizing format
grid.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true; 
grid.RenderControl(hw);

//string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

If i download as ".xlsx" format its giving following error and unable to open excel file.How can i download the excel with ".xlsx" format ?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be downloading *HTML* with an *XLS* extension that excel is happy to deal with, even though its incorrect. That seems not to be the case for XLSX.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be serving this as a .xlsx in the first place? Technically it's neither format, but Excel is converting it if it's passed as a .xls.

Comment: Learn how to generate a proper Excel file using libraries such as [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), Aspose etc. You are currently creating an HTML file, serving it with an Excel extension and MIME type. This is a terrible idea. Excel 2007 files are not HTML files. They're [Open Office XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

Comment: hi  @mason tq.Will try to implement with one of those libraries

Comment: My favorite is EPPlus. Additionally, I suggest you switch from using a DataTable and start using strongly typed models (classes that represent your data). You'll find they're far more efficient and easier to work with.